# How to display the same image with different foregrounds using CSS

Tags: html, css, graphics, colors

I want to enable my users to choose color of their avatar. It would be always the same image, but in different colors.

[image] 
[image]

Of course, I can create PNG images in every RGB color separately OR I can create only one (let's say grey) and use CSS to provide desired foreground.

Now, how can I do that? What I have tried ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/892nwztf/)):

```
<style>
    .test { width: 128px; height: 128px; }
    .red { background: red url(my_image.png) 50% 0 no-repeat; }
    .blue { background: blue url(my_image.png) 50% 0 no-repeat; }
</style>

<div class="test red"></div>
<div class="test blue"></div>
```

I've also tried reducing opacity, but it resulted in poor color quality.

Comment: Use an SVG.....instead of a png?

Comment: [Could try this.](http://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/) What you're asking for is described as "tinting."

Comment: @Compass Thanks, but IE8,9 does not support it

Answer (score 0):

You might stack up 3 divs and 2 images to achieve this. Keep a plain div and fill it with the choice of your color. Place your grey image on top with high transparency so that the color is shown on your avatar. Place another transparent gif on top of these two divs. The gif has to be a transparent on your avatar and filled with white color on the negative side of your avatar. So that you see white color square and colored avatar in the center.

Might not be the best way to do it, but It should work.